# Path enviroment variable editor BUG

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, path

Windows 10 brought new PATH environment variable editor, but for some reason, it just stopped working for me.

The odd thing is that path editor is "broken" only for system variables.. in case of User variables, the editor is fine.

System editor:

[image]

User Path editor:

[image]

As you can see, both are editing Path variable, however both use different editor. This is quite infuriating, have you ever encountered such error?

Comment: It's not an error. The system and user PATH variables are different things.

Comment: They are, however the editor is not, that should be the same because I was editing system Path with the same editor a week ago.

Comment: Ah. OK. Reopened.

Comment: Is there any problem with that type of GUI issue? If you don't go with GUI then you.may use `setx /m` command.

Comment: The new editor is much cleaner and organized, easier to navigate and to make changes. For example load priorities, that is why this bug is quite painful.. while this style of editor (which is inherited from windows 7) is working, it's not, great..

Comment: What is the error? How is it "broken"? What is the question?

Comment: The bug lies in the lack of new editor. Windows 10 shipped with new path editor for both user and system variables. I used it hundreds of times, but now, without any apparent reason, it defaulted back to "old" pre-windows 10 editor. The question is, how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try to back out Windows updates?

Comment: @LoneWanderer The issue is that the first entry on your Path variable starts with a non-built-in environment variable.  Move `%SystemRoot%\System32` (the third entry) to the front of your path, and this issue will be resolved.  Note that in your first screenshot, the background dialog displays the path as `%M2_HOME%...`, whereas the second displays the path as `C:\Users\...`.  That indicates that `USERPROFILE` is a built-in Windows environment variable, but `M2_HOME` is not (This can be verified by observing USERPROFILE isn't listed in HKCU\Environment).  See my answer for more details.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any new line or other unprintable characters either. It happened to me...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue, and *finally* figured this out via trial-and-error.  The issue is that there is a bug in the Windows 10 Path environment variable parser.  In my case, the first entry in my Path environment variable started with an application-defined REG_SZ environment variable (e.g., Path was set to `%MyAppPath%\some\subdir;...`).  From my testing, it appears that the first entry on the Path must not start with a non-built-in environment variable.

For example, if my Path environment variable were set to `%SystemRoot%;%MyAppPath%\some\subdir;...`, it would be editable in the Path list view editor, since `SystemRoot` is a built-in environment variable.  If you swap the first two paths in that example, I observed the symptom you describe (that editing the Path variable results in opening the standard text editing dialog instead of the Path list editor).

To fix this issue, ensure the first entry in your Path doesn't start with a non-built-in environment variable.

Comment: Note that this issue has been resolved by Microsoft.

Comment: Jeff G, I still have that problem. How can I get that fix from Microsoft?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not exactly certain when this fix was rolled out.  What I do know is that this symptom is no longer occurring on any of my machines, which are Windows 10 Enterprise 1709 build 16299.904, and Windows 10 Professional 1703 build 15063.1029.  Is your system up-to-date?  What is your Windows version/OS build #?

Comment: I currently use Windows 10 Professional 1809 build 11763.253. Your trick with not starting the Path with a non-built-in environment variable worked, but was actually required.

Comment: I'm use Windows 10 Professional 1903 build 18362.239 and the bug still exists. What i did instead for the fix was to add a place holder as the first entry called C:\myPlaceholder and it worked fine. It doesn't seem to make a difference that the folder does not exist on the drive.

Comment: I'm still unable to reproduce this on Windows 10 Pro 1803 build 17134.885.  I have attempted starting my path with environment variables that are type REG_SZ and REG_EXPAND_SZ.  I've tried creating variables without the word "Path" in the name.  All of my tests are passing.  I'm going to update to 1903 and see if there has been a regression, then report back here.  You may want to contact Microsoft and see if they can identify which patch this fix was rolled out in, and manually apply that patch to your computer.  Can one of you give an example of a path that isn't opening the correct editor?

Comment: I updated to 18362.267, and still cannot reproduce this issue.  If those of you still observing this can either 1) contact Microsoft directly, and report back your findings, or 2) give us more information (e.g., what is the value of the variable you are using as the first entry on the path?) so we can investigate further.

Comment: Mine is Enterprise 1903 18362.295.  If I have the SYSTEM PATH start with %CDSROOT%\tools\bin before %SYSTEMROOT%\system32, then it shows up in the single row like the first picture.  If I have %SYSTEMROOT%\system32 before, then it shows up in the multi-row editor.  %CDSROOT% is system variable with value C:\Cadence\SPB_17.2

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not able to reproduce.  The only way I am able to break the editor is to make the first path in the good dialog `;%CDSROOT%`.  Then, the old, much less usable dialog pops up.  When I remove the semicolon (and quotes), it gets fixed again.  Sorry that I couldn't be more help, but hopefully it was either fixed by some patch applied to your computer, or you were able to get help directly from MS.

Comment: hello from 2021. I just experienced this issue myself, and *the solution given here works*... I think I'm not on 21H1 yet (??) but this definitely is still happening.

Comment: hello from 2023. Paraphrasing @ChristophRackwitz, I also experienced this issue myself. I'm working on 22H2 dated 25.Oct.2020 OSBuild 19045.2965. And **the solution giver here still works**. One caveat on the solution. For Windows to display the Editor properly, if your PATH variable has only one entry it must end in a semi-colon.

Comment: Hello from 11/2023. The issue is still a problem and I'm working on Win10 Ent 22H2 OSBuild 19045.3570. And **the solution given here still works**. The other thing to note is that the first **OR SECOND** entry in PATH must not contain an environment variable--it doesn't have to the be first.